# Simplify output for combn function to remove spaces and row and column markers

Tags: r, spacing, combn

I would like to take a data set like the one below generated using the combn function:

https://i.ibb.co/r0qSmYV/example.jpg

and have it print

1111112223
2223343344
3454544555

the current solutions I have tried are trimws() and gsub(). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post your code as image. You can use `dput` to share your data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
libary(tidyverse)
as.data.frame(combn(1:5, 3)) |>  rowwise() |> 
mutate(
  txt = paste0(c_across(),collapse = "")
) |> pull(txt) |> cat(fill=1L)
```

Comment: This is precisely the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much, you are a lifesaver.

Comment: Do you possibly know the modification to make it so that when I output to a text file there isn't a space following each row entry? My current workaround is to use MS Word and Ctrl+H, check 'Use wildcards' and search for the spaces using ( ){1,}, and replace them with nothing. For my larger data sets it seems the copy/paste function isn't working when I go to copy the data set with the removed spaces back to the .txt file, nor does the save feature it seems, so a direct solution may be needed. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: mycontent <- as.data.frame(combn(1:5, 3)) |>  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(
    txt = paste0(c_across(),collapse = "")
  ) |> pull(txt) 
;
writeLines(mycontent,
           con="myfile.txt")

Comment: Wonderful! Your solution works like a charm and I hope this thread will be useful to many in the future. Thank you, Nir.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
combn(1:5, 3) |> 
  as.data.frame() |>
  mutate(combined = apply(across(everything()), 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ""))) |> 
  pull(combined)
```

which gives:

```
[1] "1111112223" "2223343344" "3454554555"
```

of course, if you don't want to just have a vector and instead have a data frame column, don't run the last line.